# In PyQt QTreeView item, how to set color for specific column blocks

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview

With PyQt4 based QTreeView, I've created 2 xml tree widgets. From both the trees, want to compare selected items and highlight the difference. For e.g.,

Left String : "CompareString"
Right String : "ComPareStringRight"

The observations of the diff :

- Left[0:2] is same as Right[0:2]
- Left[3:3] differs with Right[3:3]
- Left[4-12] is same as Right[4-12]
- Right[13-17] is not present in Left

Now, want to set colors according to :

- matching characters - default
- Differing characters - Orange
- Added characters - Green
- Deleted characters - Red

How can I implement this? Unable to find any reference implementation to pick up from. Pls suggest a way forward.

> ```
> class QCustomDelegate (QItemDelegate):
>   global showDiffPaint
>   def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
>     column = indexQModelIndex.column()
>     if showDiffPaint == 1:
>       QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)
>     else:
>       QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

After digging, found it useful to convert text into html, and present as below.
However, found bugs due to " and < and > characters display. which I think I need to escape somehow...

```
      options = QStyleOptionViewItemV4(option)
      doc = QTextDocument()
      doc.setHtml(txt1)
      doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
      style = QApplication.style()
      style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, options, painter)
      ctx = QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()
      textRect = style.subElementRect(QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText,
                                    options)
      painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
      painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
      doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)
```